# Completely silent mode for Installscript installation

Tags: installshield, installscript, installshield-2011

I have an installscript projects which accepts some prefined command line arguments. Depending upon the arguments passed to it, certain features are selected and installation is performed.
I want this installation to be without any User interaction, even the dialogs should not be visible on the screen like we have /qn mode for msi installation.
How can I achieve it for installscript project.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a command line based on the information found here: [Installshield Setup.exe Command line settings](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield20helplib/Content/helplibrary/IHelpSetup_EXECmdLine.htm).

Some Installshield Installscript setups need a response file created to run silently, and even then there might be cases where it doesn't run entirely silently. This is just how this project type works. Response files are created by running Setup.exe with the /r option.

[**More information here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64285550/129130).