# Creating a response file for msi installer

Tags: automation, windows-installer, silent-installer

I have an .msi installer that I am trying to automate the installation for. I cannot use the /quiet option for a silent install because I need to provide the installer a license number.

I've been trying to use the SAVEINI parameter to create the response file

```
msiexec /i "Installer.msi" SAVEINI="response_file"

msiexec /i "Installer.msi" SAVEINI="response_file.ini"

msiexec /i "Installer.msi" SAVEINI="C:/Windows/LTSvc/packages/Installer/response_file"
```

None of these create the response file the install runs and then no response file is created.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Little time right now, but [maybe have a look here](https://resources.flexera.com/web/pdf/archive/silent_installs.pdf). And [maybe here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51941558/129130).

Answer (score 1):

Windows Installer doesn't have the concept of a response file.  Instead you pass public properties at the commandline or generate a transform and apply it at install tine.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/about-transforms

Comment: Yes, good point - with the exception of [Installscript MSI files that need response files and setup.exe launch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52022726/129130) - unless you use the [ISSSETUPDRIVEN=1 trick](https://www.itninja.com/question/issetupdriven-2) to eliminate the need for a setup.exe launch. [How to deploy the Installshield MSI without having to run Setup.exe](https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article?legacyId=HOWTO4204)